# Android Pay in Hybrid Apps

Tags: android, android-pay

Has anyone had any experience integrating Android Pay in Hybrid Apps?

To use an example: WebView has an HTML button that should trigger Android Pay workflow. How can we trigger MaskedWallet and FullWallet without rendering the button first?

Answer (score 0):

Its just tricky you can make a custom view in hybrid application and then can implement android pay . You have to check first is android pay is installed or not in device if its callback return success then you have to implement android pay functionality.

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Comment: i integrated Braintree as it includes gpay and applepay, in mobile chrome browser, it works fine but in hybrid app, it returns false when i check for gpay support.